# css align ul li horizontal not working (now it's diagonal)

Tags: css, html-lists, vertical-alignment, alignment

On Wordpress i'm using youtube channel list plugin.

It works well, but the align of the videos don't looks great. Actually display diagonal list below the BIG video!

Can someone suggest me how to fix this issue with css?

here's the page

http://www.snowypeach.com/home/?page_id=1106

I need the list under the video aligned horizontal, not diagonal!

Comment: lots if invalid HTML ... fix those issues first ..

Comment: fixed, nothing is changed

Comment: you have removed the opening `<div>` but have left in the `</div>`. You also have `div` elements inside `pre` which is invalid, `div`s inside `a` are also invalid...

Comment: i've deleted pre too! thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have nested a `<div />` as a child of the `<ul />`. This is invalid markup. Move the `<li/>` elements to be the children of the `<ul />`, delete the `<div />` and it will work

**EDIT**

Okay I see the problem. You are wrapping all this content within a `<pre/>` tag. This tag shouldn't be used here but if you are unable to get rid of it add the style `white-space: normal;`.

I tested the previous answer by moving elements within chrome dev tools which removed the whitespace and therefore the problem.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: @stefano great! Really recommend you try removed that element if possible though :)

Comment: @Inrbob cool man even i was troubling from last half an hour and i tried all the possibilities but i did not know that <pre> tag can give that much trouble.

Answer (score 0):

There is class **ytc-columns4** on the below `<ul>` which is taking control over the alignment of the small video `<li>` tags

```
<ul class="ytchagallery ytccf ytc-table ytc-td-bottom ytc-columns4">
```

according to that class the below css is generating by plugin in the css file on line 66

```
http://www.snowypeach.com/home/wp-content/plugins/youtube-channel-gallery/styles.css?ver=3.4.1

.ytc-columns4 li {
    width: calc(100% / 4 + 10px / 3);
}
```

i have changed the class **ytc-columns3** and **ytc-columns2** and result vary every time. I am not exactly getting where is the calculation part of the plugin. Other wise i can tweek the code.

Comment: here's the plugin official page:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/youtube-channel-gallery/

on the admin you can set how many columns as you want. I don't care about the number...i just want to fix the diagonal issue :(